# Removing application use(r)-generated files with WiX

Tags: wix, uninstallation, user-data

Currently, our user data hierarchy looks like this:

LocalAppDataFolder/Company/Product

This makes sense as far as it goes because a user might have multiple products installed. However, WiX will not let me remove just the Product folder.

```
<Directory Id="LocalAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="ManufacturerDir" Name="Company">
        <Directory Id="AppDataDir" Name="Product">
            <Component Id="AppData" Guid="some_guid">
                <RemoveFolder Id="AppDataDir" On="uninstall" />
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Company\Product" Type="string" Value="" />
            </Component>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

The above snippet causes the error, "LGHT0204 : ICE64: The directory Company is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table." Obviously, I don't want to wipe the data from other products. Several examples that I've found are only one directory deep, i.e. they do not include an intervening directory, in this case Company.

I get the feeling that I am misunderstanding something here. What? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `<RemoveFolder Id="RemoveManufacturerDir" Directory="ManufacturerDir" On="Uninstall"/>` should get rid of that error. The folder will only get removed if the directory is empty. If there are other files in there, it will not be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't tell if I misunderstand you, or you me. :) Just to reiterate: I don't **want** to remove the Company directory, just the Product directory.

Comment: It's amazing what a bit of fresh air can do. I understand what you meant now. Thanks!

Comment: This just caught me out as well -- the thing I missed was that the `Id` of `<RemoveFolder>` should be a new ID and not the ID of the folder as defined in `<Directory>`